# Como colorir parte de um texto dentro do input usando REGEX ou se tem algum plugin do VUEJS

Tags: html, css, regex, vue.js, plugin

Meu problema é o seguinte eu tenho um input com o texto.

Ex.: "Vou adicionar este novo texto".

Quando está selecionado o texto eu troco ele para ficar entre chaves.

Ex.: "Vou {{adicionar}} este novo texto".
**ATÉ AQUI CONSEGUI**

Mas eu preciso trocar todos os lugares para onde estiver entre **{{}}** colocar em **NEGRITO e AMARELO** por exemplo.

Por isso citei usar regex ou me indicar algum plugin que faça isso enquanto eu estou digitando dentro do input.

Comment: Se possível, poste seu HTML e script que tiver até o momento para que eu consiga ajudar melhor. Obrigado.